# How to append raw bytes to std::vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I want to append the raw bytes into `vector` like this.

```
vector.reserve(current_size + append_data_size);
memcpy(append_data, vector.data() + current_size, append_data_size);
vector.resize(current_size  + append_data_size) // Expect only set size to current_size + append_data_size.
```

does below is slower? because I think vector is initialised to default first then set the data which is waste.

```
vector.resize(current_size  + append_data_size);
memcpy(append_data, vector.data() + current_size, append_data_size);
```

Comment: When `resize` enlarges a vector, it creates new values (even if there is already space for them). The `reserve` operation just makes space.

Comment: If you want to add data to a vector, use its interface.  For instance `vector.insert(iter_pos_into_vec, start_of_range_to_copy, end_of_range_to_copy)`

Comment: You say you want to append, but you're using `memcmp()` for that!? Also, what is `n`? Why would `n + 100` become `100`?

Comment: Now, check the arguments of `memcpy()`. That is exactly why you're required to provide a [mcve], btw. It avoids code that doesn't compile and doesn't work, thus obfuscating the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modifying vector storage beyond its size is undefined behavior, and a subsequent `resize` will initialize the new elements at the end of the storage.

However, you could use `insert` instead:

```
vector.insert(vector.end(), bytes, bytes + size);
```

Comment: Mind you, this will convert from `decltype(*bytes)` to `vector::value_type`, whereas the `memcpy` will copy raw bits.

Comment: Right. And where `insert` is not the same as `memcpy`, I bet you want `insert`.

Answer (score 5):

Even if you call `reserve`, you still must call `resize` on the vector if you want to access the new elements, otherwise the behaviour of your code is *undefined*. What `reserve` *can* do is make `push_back` and other such operations more efficient.

Personally I wouldn't concern yourself with any such optimisations unless you can prove they have an effect with an appropriate profiling tool. More often than not, fiddling with the capacity of a `std::vector` is pointless.

Also using `memcpy` is hazardous. (Copy constructors will not be called for example, knowledge of the exact behaviour of copying padding in structures with `memcpy` for example is a sure way of increasing your reputation on this site!) Use `insert` instead and trust the compiler to optimise as appropriate.

Without an explicit additional parameter, std::vector::resize *value-initialises* any additional members. Informally that means the elements of a `std::vector` of `T` say are set to values in the same way as the `t` in `static T t;` would be.